# Expression obviously does not return the right value

Tags: wpf, reflection, binding, expression

my application uses MarkupExtensions in order to accomplish automatic translation of the user interface. This works insanely great at runtime but it does not at design-time. Normally this wouldn't be much of a problem but once you have about 40 controls which are bound to translation, you see 40 erros which say "Object not set to an instance." because the Translator is not instanced. Moreover would it be really nice to see how it actually looks when there's translated text instead of "!keyname!". This helps desinging the UI significantly.

Unfortunately my application is very abstract and modular and because I don't want to reference the Localization assembly I had to do some nasty tricks to enable design-time translation.

One class is always in use and safe for use at design-time. It's the Core which gives access to everything (including the Localization assembly, but that one is not instanced at design-time). So I added some code to the static constructor of the Core which looks up for the assembly and creates the Translator through Reflection/Expressions. This obviously works as I got an exception which occured in the Translator's constructor.

But when I try to assign the instance of the Translator to the property in the Core, which will later be used to create design-time translation bindings, I have to notice that there is no instance set. When the MarkupExtensions are created I get an exception which tells me that there's no DesignTimeTranslator set.

I can't figure out why this happens and because of this running at design-time, I can't debug well. I'm not that much into Expressions so I don't know what happens when they fail to execute nor what should be the actual output (but I guess it should be ITranslator).

```
if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())) return;
try
{
    Assembly locA = Assembly.Load(
                                  AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                                                                            "Localization.dll")));
    if (locA == null) throw new Exception("No DesignTimeTranslator assembly found.");
    Type locT = locA.GetType("Localization.Translator");
    if (locT == null) throw new Exception("DesignTimeTranslator type not found.");
    ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = locT.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                          null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    if (constructorInfo == null) throw new Exception("No constructor found for DesignTimeTranslator.");
    NewExpression constrExp = Expression.New(constructorInfo);
    Func<object> constructor = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(constrExp, null).Compile();

    DesignTimeTranslator = (ITranslator)constructor();
    MessageBox.Show(DesignTimeTranslator != null ? DesignTimeTranslator.GetType().FullName : "No Translator :(");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("[DESIGNTIME] Exception occured: {0}{1}".FormatWith(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    MessageBox.Show(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                                 "Localization.dll"));
}
```

Here's the translator's constructor:

```
internal Translator()
{
    bool designTime = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject());
    if (_instance != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Can´t create another Translator instance!");
    _instance = this;

    this._languagePacks = new Dictionary<CultureInfo, LangFormat>();
}
```

Thanks :)